# Como remover parte escura nas laterais do carousel bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou fazendo um sistema de rolagem para mostras algumas tabelas usando um carousel, mas o mesmo por padrão fica com uma tonalidade mais escura nas laterais e ate na própria tabela, como e possível remover esse cor deixando apenas as tabelas e os botões ?

Não estou usando nada alem do html e bootstrap ate o momento

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="panel panel-default col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel-heading" ss>
          <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Ficha 1 para o aluno: Y</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Treino</th>
                <th class="text-center">1</th>
                <th class="text-center">Intervalo</th>
                <th class="text-center">%esf</th>
                <th class="text-center">FC</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Aquecimento</th>
                <td>
                  <div class="row col-md-12 col-md-offset-0" style="background-color: aqua">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>1x</option>
                        <option>2x</option>
                        <option>3x</option>
                        <option>4x</option>
                        <option>5x</option>
                        <option>6x</option>
                        <option>7x</option>
                        <option>8x</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>1x</option>
                        <option>2x</option>
                        <option>3x</option>
                        <option>4x</option>
                        <option>5x</option>
                        <option>6x</option>
                        <option>7x</option>
                        <option>8x</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>10m</option>
                        <option>50mx</option>
                        <option>100m</option>
                        <option>150m</option>
                        <option>200m</option>
                        <option>300m</option>
                        <option>400m</option>
                        <option>500m</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Alternado</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Braços</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Resistência</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Pernas</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Educativo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Progressivo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Regenerativo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">




      <div class="panel panel-default col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel-heading" ss>
          <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Ficha 2 para o aluno: Y</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Treino</th>
                <th class="text-center">1</th>
                <th class="text-center">Intervalo</th>
                <th class="text-center">%esf</th>
                <th class="text-center">FC</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Aquecimento</th>
                <td>
                  <div class="row col-md-12 col-md-offset-0" style="background-color: aqua">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>1x</option>
                        <option>2x</option>
                        <option>3x</option>
                        <option>4x</option>
                        <option>5x</option>
                        <option>6x</option>
                        <option>7x</option>
                        <option>8x</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>1x</option>
                        <option>2x</option>
                        <option>3x</option>
                        <option>4x</option>
                        <option>5x</option>
                        <option>6x</option>
                        <option>7x</option>
                        <option>8x</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>10m</option>
                        <option>50mx</option>
                        <option>100m</option>
                        <option>150m</option>
                        <option>200m</option>
                        <option>300m</option>
                        <option>400m</option>
                        <option>500m</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Alternado</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Braços</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Resistência</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Pernas</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Educativo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Progressivo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Regenerativo</th>
                <td>Conteúdo</td>
                <td>Intervalo</td>
                <td>%esf</td>
                <td>FC</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arcashaid vc vai precisar fazer um override de css em carousel.less e bootstrap.css

Depois que vc tirar o gradiente escuro dos cantos vc vai ver que as setas de navegação vão ficar com pouco contraste por serem na cor #fff, então coloquei em #000 pra te ajudar. Também mantive o `background-image` caso vc mude de ideia é só voltar com a cor

```
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.carousel-control {
    color: black;
}

.carousel-control:focus, .carousel-control:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

**Essa folha de estilo deve vir após o bootstrap, conforme abaixo:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override-bootstrap.css">
```